# Why are vectors considered to have odd/negative/- parity while pseudovectors are even/positive/+ in parity?

Tags: tensor-calculus, vectors, terminology, parity

Most places I read say that true/polar vectors are of odd or - parity, while axial/pseudovectors are of even + parity.

But, pseudovectors gain an 'extra' sign flip after a reflection/parity transformation...  Also, they are the ones called -pseudo'...

I thought that 'objects' of whatever type that gained extra sign flip(s) after a 'mirror reflection' (parity transformation) were, by definition, of negative/odd parity...

In short, I am confused about the parity of vectors and pseudovectors...

Comment: It's the same definition in mathematics, for example an odd function is one such that $f(-x)=-f(x)$, while even functions follow $f(-x)=f(x)$.

Comment: "Most places I read say that true/polar vectors are of odd or - parity" If there are any that say otherwise they are wrong.

Comment: The extra minus sign of a pseudo-vector is *added to*  the built-in minus sign of a vector.  A vector is said to have odd parity *because* it has a built-in minus sign.  It's not extra, it's built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cross product of two polar vector forms an axial vector. Say vector $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ under inversion operation [ $P_i ( \vec{r} ) \rightarrow -\vec{r}$].

$$
    P_i (\vec{A}) = -\vec{A}; \text{ and } P_i (\vec{B}) = -\vec{B}
$$

Then we examine the $\vec{C} = \vec{A} \times \vec{B}$

$$
   P_i(\vec{C}) = P_i( \vec{A} \times \vec{B}) =P_i (\vec{A}) \times P_i (\vec{B}) = \vec{C} . 
$$

This make $\vec{C}$ an axial vector.

[image]